# ¿Cómo acomodar <Card/> en esta vista con React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Cuando tengo una pregunta muy larga se activa el scroll horizontal y además toca usarlo para ver los datos dentro de la `Card`, quiero que se acomoden dentro del margen que ven en pantalla, es decir, que no importa que ocupe una línea entera para mostrar el texto completo o que se deforme el texto para ocupar varias líneas con tal de que no se tenga que activar el scroll horizontal.

Así se ve cuando no hay preguntas que sean muy largas, bueno, en este caso, son toda la misma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y esto ocurre cuando una pregunta es muy larga (imagino que con el campo categoría o Nivel ('Junior') también puede ocurrir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar, se deforman las `<Card>` y se activa el scroll horizontal, pero quiero que mantengan un aspecto relativamente parecido al de la primera imagen. O que aunque se deformen no ocupen más que el espacio dentro del margen que aparece en la primera imagen. No quiero que se active el scroll horizontal para tener que ver todo. Es decir, que se ajusten a ese margen como límite o que el texto se coloque en múltiples líneas hasta cuando llega a ese margen.

Este es el código que crea el  que contiene los  con las Card:

```
const questionList = testQuestions.map(question => {
    return (
      <Grid item xs>
        <Description
          description={question.desc}
          category={question.category}
          level={question.level}
          options={question.options}
        />
      </Grid>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <div className={classes.container}>
          <ResumeBar />
          <Grid
            container
            className={classes.CardContainer}
            spacing={4}
            alignItems='stretch'
            justify='flex-start'
            direction='row'
          >
            <Grid item xs>
              <AddPregunta />
            </Grid>
            {questionList}
          </Grid>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
```

Así es como está hecha cada `<Card>`:

```
return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardContent>
        <List
          component='nav'
          aria-labelledby='nested-list-subheader'
          subheader={
            <ListSubheader component='div' id='nested-list-subheader'>
              Detalles de pregunta
            </ListSubheader>
          }
          className={classes.root}
        ></List>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <TitleIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <Typography noWrap>{props.description}</Typography>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <CategoryIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <Typography>{props.category}</Typography>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <EmojiObjectsIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <Typography>{props.level}</Typography>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button onClick={handleClick}>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <ListIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <Typography>Respuestas</Typography>
          {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
        </ListItem>
        <Collapse in={open} timeout='auto' unmountOnExit>
          <List component='div' disablePadding>
            {anwerList}
          </List>
        </Collapse>
      </CardContent>

      <CardActions>
        <Button size='small'>Editar</Button>
        <Button size='small'>Eliminar</Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a pasarle la propiedad `max-width` de CSS para limitar el ancho? Depende el comportamiento que esperes podrías usar también `overflow-x: hidden`

Comment: Sí, lo solucione con un par de propiedades max sobreescribiendo las propiedades CSS del componente de material-ui.
Por favor, si deseas la respuesta correcta publica una respuesta.